# What may be the problem with Clang's -fmerge-all-constants?

Tags: compilation, clang

The compilation flag `-fmerge-all-constants` merges identical constants into a single variable. I keep reading that this results in non-conforming code, and Linus Torvalds wrote that it's inexcusable, but why?

What can possibly happen when you merge two or more identical constant variables?

Comment: Then two different variables might have the same address.  The C/C++ standards promise that will never happen, and some programs rely on that promise.  For instance, they might use pointers to specific constant objects as sentinel pointer values, and need to distinguish which is which.

Answer (score 3):

There are times when programs declare a constant object because they need something with a unique address, and there are times when any address that points to storage holding the proper sequence of byte values would be equally usable.  In C, if one writes:

```
char const * const HelloShared1 = "Hello";
char const * const HelloShared2 = "Hello";
char const HelloUnique1[] = "Hello";
char const HelloUnique2[] = "Hello";
```

a compiler would have to reserve space for at least three copies of the word Hello, followed by a zero byte.  The names `HelloUnique1` and `HelloUnique2` would refer to two of those copies, and the names `HelloShared1` and `HelloShared2` would need to identify storage that was distinct from that used by `HelloUnique1` and `HelloUnique2`, but `HelloShared1` and `HelloShared2` could at the compiler's convenience identify the same storage.

Unfortunately, while the C and C++ Standards usefully provides two ways of specifying objects that hold string literal data, so as to allow programmers to indicate when multiple copies of the same information may be placed in the same storage, it fails to specify any means of specifying the same semantics for any other kind of constant data.  For most kinds of applications, situations where a program would care about whether two objects share the same address would be far less common than those where using the same storage for constant objects holding the same data would be advantageous.

Being able to invite an implementation to make optimizations which would not be allowable by the Standard is useful, if one recognizes that programs should not be expected to be compatible with all optimizations, nor vice versa, and if compiler writers do a good job of documenting what kinds of programs different optimizations are compatible with and letting compiler writers enable only optimizations that are known to be compatible with their code.

Fundamentally, optimizations that assume programs won't do X will be useful for applications that don't involve doing X, but at best counter-productive for those that do.  The described optimizations would fall into this category.  I wouldn't see any basis for complaining about a compiler that makes such optimizations available *but doesn't enable them by default*.  On the other hand, some people believe any program that isn't compatible with any imaginable optimization as "broken".